# python "is" and "==" problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean, jupyter-notebook, equals

I found an interesting thing of using "is" to judge whether two variable are same.
Here are my code and results:

```
a = 256
b = 256
c = 257
d = 257
print(a is b)
print(c is d)
```

and the results show:

```
True
False
```

Actually, when the number is bigger than 256, it turns 'False'.

Another example:

```
a = 'a' * 20
b = 'a' * 20
c = 'a' * 21
d = 'a' * 21
print(a is b)
print(c is d)
```

Results:

```
True
False
```

Similarly, when n in "'a' * n" is bigger than 20, it turns 'False'.

But when I put this into a function, it doesn't matter how big is the number:

```
def is_test(a):
    x = a
    y = a
    print(x is y)

is_test(257)
is_test('a' * 21)
```

the results are always 'True'

I ran the code on Jupyter Notebook.
Anyone can explain this to me? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

is checks if they are the same object(same place in memory) == checks if they are of equal value, low values are pre stored an thus point to the same memory space. for example, it would be stupid to write a new 1 and 0 every time it was needed just because it's for a new use, since those two numbers are being used so often so they just point to a prewritten datatable containing 1 and 0, among with low numbers and other often used values.

Answer (score 0):

First, `is` checks whether the two identifiers are references to the same object, while `==` checks for equality, and it calls `__eq__()` where applicable.

In CPython, integral numbers from -5 to 256 are "cached" at startup, and when you do `a = 256`, you just get back a reference to the predefined `int` object. For 257 and up, it's created on-the-go, so you may get two `int` objects with value 257.

For strings of length 20 and less, and whose value is a valid identifier*, they're also cached the same way. That's why when you define such strings twice you get the same object reference.

* For example, the value of string `"a1b2c3"` is a valid identifier, while `">:})_!#*^"` isn't.

[Source](https://github.com/satwikkansal/wtfpython/blob/master/README.md#-is-is-not-what-it-is).

Answer (score 0):

You can reference to [Plain Integer Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html) here.

"The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object. So it should be possible to change the value of 1. I suspect the behaviour of Python in this case is undefined. :-)"

That's why you will get the same id() for number of -5 ~ 256.
As for other numbers, it would be referenced differently.

**is** is the way to identify is the are referencing the same object, but **==** checks for if the values are equal.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 256
b = 256
c = a

if (a == b):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")

if (a is b):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")

if (a is c):
    print("True")
else:    
    print("False")
```

## Output:

```
True
False
True
```

## Description

1. `True`: Output of the first `if condition` is `True` as both `a` and `b` have
   same value.
2. `False`: Second `if condition` shows `False` because `a` and `b` are at
   different memory locations. Hence they refer to different objects.
   We can check it with `id()` function in python which returns the `identity` of 
   an object.
3. `True`: Output of the third `if condition` is `True` as both `a` and `c`
   are pointing to the same object.